# MAMP very slow to serve pages using Virtual Hosts on OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I am running MAMP 4.1.1 on my mac mini with OSX Sierra (10.12.3).

lately when I try to load pages for a site using a virtual host, it is VERY slow to load.

if i load pages without a virtual host it comes up very quick.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       mydevsite.com
fe80::1%lo0     mydevsite.com
```

in my httpd-vhosts.conf file I have the following:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
NameVirtualHost mydevsite.com:80

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mydevsite.com"
ServerName mydevsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to troubleshoot this further to get my local sites using virtual hosts to server quickly?